# How to use signalr as a client in asp.net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Signalr is usually used in "server" side asp.net through hubs and connections. What I'm trying to accomplish (if possible) is using signalr as a "client" in a website.
I have 2 websites, one as a server and another as a client.

I tried this

```
public void Start()
    {
        new Task(this.Listen).Start();
        //new Thread(this.Listen).Start();
    }
    private async void Listen()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8081"))
            {
                var myHub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("mediaHub");

                hubConnection.StateChanged += change => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(change.OldState + " => " + change.NewState);

                myHub.On<string>(
                    "log",
                    message =>
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message + " Notified !")); 

                await hubConnection.Start();                 

            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
             // ... 
        }
    }
```

The server is calling the client like this:

```
        var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MediaHub>() ;
        hub.Clients.All.log("Server: " + message);
```

Nothing reaches the client !

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: No browser involved, it's .NET client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as your connection  is ready, you actually dispose it, so it does not stay around. As a quick test, remove the `using` stuff and make your `hubConnection` a static member of your class, and check if you get called. If you do, then from there you can refine it, but at least you have clearer what's going on.